# What is the purpose of a negative feedback resistor in a schmitt trigger?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, oscillator, schmitt-trigger, negative-feedback

[image: schematic of schmitt trigger]

This schmitt trigger is used with an integrator to create a triangle/square wave oscillator but R5 has been added to the typical inverting schmitt trigger topology. I know that in simulation, this changes the symmetry of the triangle wave but in trying to analyse I can't show why this would be. Why does adding negative feedback change the rate of change of the output? How would you match the rate of change in the rise and fall i.e. make the triangle wave symmetrical?

Comment: Is Vref an ideal voltage source or does it have a series resistor?

Comment: It is coming from an opamp (LM358) in a buffer configuration, so it is quite ideal I think

Comment: In that case R5 will have no effect other than putting a load on the output of the comparator and reducing the voltage - that will change the symmetry. Show the rest of the circuit.